# Ambiguous column name for order by the selected column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I never notice below before:

```
SELECT A,* 
FROM Table
ORDER BY A
```

It gives me the `Ambiguous column name` error. The `*` of course contains `A`, but will sql server take the same column `A` in above query as two different columns? Is this the reason behind that?

Comment: In this simplistic case no, but this is just a general syntax issue. Since you could also say `SELECT A = B, A AS B, * ... ORDER BY A` for example. Basically you should strive to make each output column name unique.

Comment: alright, just curious cuz I never pay attention to above syntax lol

Answer (score 2):

it is because the output has the same name if you did

```
SELECT A AS A_STANDS_ALONE,* 
FROM Table
ORDER BY A
```

It will work

Comment: Thanks :)))) @ Hogan

Comment: Can also just say `ORDER BY 1` and it will sort by the first column in the `SELECT`.

Comment: @Zack on some systems

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for yes/no answer, then 'YES', you are right. 
SQL Selects A column twice, one by explicit and one by the implicit * call.
SQL doesn't understand which one you want to sort by.
The first comment to your post shows that you can use an alias for the column.

Comment: Thanks :)))) @ Denys